# Excel macro to write win. metadata for an exported pdf e.g. 'Comments' field

Tags: vba, excel, metadata

I have an Excel 2007 macro that creates an Invoice in pdf format.
I'm now trying to write the Invoice Value in the 'Comments' field (in the file's meta data) - so that it can be seen when viewing the Invoice folder in File Explorer.

I've been able to write the value to the excel file itself, with

```
'save & close the spreadsheet
 ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments").Value = "£" & Amount
 ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

And I can create the .pdf  OK, with

```
'Create pdf. save it and display it on-screen - for user to print
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:=ThisFile, _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

But I haven't been able to find the syntax to write the meta data to the .pdf

```
'Create pdf. save it and display on-screen:  for user to print/email
Amount = Range("J116").Value
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Comments").Value = "£" & Amount
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=ThisFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

How can this be best/easiest achieved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a PDF doesn't have a "Comments" property like Office documents. Have a look here: [Why are Acrobat PDF tags not shown in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/602536/why-are-acrobat-pdf-tags-not-shown-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ   - I already have https://filemeta.codeplex.com/ - so tried using 'Subject' rather than 'Comments' and it works.